# How can I change the text in my desktop environment's taskbar (or in panel using Linux) for my VS Code windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, taskbar

I want to change the text shown in my taskbar (panel), I always open more than one window and I would prefer the project name instead of the opened file name.

[image]

Comment: you should specify/describe the desired outcome _in text_ and not in text inside an image (see [ask]).

Answer (score 1):

If that label in your desktop environment's taskbar is just based on the window title (which it looks like is the case, and I'd wager is really the case), then you should modify your `window.title` setting in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) to be `"${folderName}"`.

Comment: thanks, in Ubuntu is opening `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` and typing: `"window.title": "${dirty}${folderName}"`

Comment: @danilo answer updated. I didn't include the `${dirty}` variable because your question doesn't ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
Open settings: Menu `File -> Preferences -> Settings`
Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

Type: Window Title

Change to: `${dirty}${folderName}`

[image]

[image]