# Why are the items in the context menu of the VS Code shortcut in the Windows taskbar for SSH workspaces not consistent?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code to edit files in a /data folder on two different servers via ssh connection. I used the official docs to set this up: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

Now in the first case, the item in the context menu of the VS Code shortcut in the Windows bar shows `data [SSH: servername]` while in the second case it just shows `data`. I would like the second link to also show `data [SSH: servername]`. I tried to find out where these shortcuts are stored, but didn't succeed. Can anybody help me?

[image: print screen]

Additional information:

If I start the two pinned shortcuts from the context menu of my vs code shortcut in my taskbar, then it looks like this:

[image]

So the configured window title of vs code seems to be fine.

I searched the registry, but didn't find any results.

I don't have a local .settings file for these projects, because I am not opening a local workspace, but rather I connect directly to the remote server.

I do see both servers as expected in the remote explorer.

Comment: if you start VSC plain and go to the Remote Explorer don't you see both server names in the SSH Targets, you can try to find it in the registry

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The windows title seems to be ok - it shows actually exactly what I would like to see in the shortcuts as well. I updated my question accordingly. So my issue ist "just" the shortcut which does not show the server name in one of the two cases ...

Answer (score 1):

As I've stated before in my answer to [How can I change the text in my desktop environment's taskbar (or in panel using Linux) for my VS Code windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75582054/11107541), the text here is based on the window title, which you can control via VS Code settings. Quoting from defaultSettings.json:

> ```json
> // Controls the window title based on the current context such as the opened workspace or active editor. Variables are substituted based on the context:
> // - `${activeEditorShort}`: the file name (e.g. myFile.txt).
> // - `${activeEditorMedium}`: the path of the file relative to the workspace folder (e.g. myFolder/myFileFolder/myFile.txt).
> // - `${activeEditorLong}`: the full path of the file (e.g. /Users/Development/myFolder/myFileFolder/myFile.txt).
> // - `${activeFolderShort}`: the name of the folder the file is contained in (e.g. myFileFolder).
> // - `${activeFolderMedium}`: the path of the folder the file is contained in, relative to the workspace folder (e.g. myFolder/myFileFolder).
> // - `${activeFolderLong}`: the full path of the folder the file is contained in (e.g. /Users/Development/myFolder/myFileFolder).
> // - `${folderName}`: name of the workspace folder the file is contained in (e.g. myFolder).
> // - `${folderPath}`: file path of the workspace folder the file is contained in (e.g. /Users/Development/myFolder).
> // - `${rootName}`: name of the workspace with optional remote name and workspace indicator if applicable (e.g. myFolder, myRemoteFolder [SSH] or myWorkspace (Workspace)).
> // - `${rootNameShort}`: shortened name of the workspace without suffixes (e.g. myFolder, myRemoteFolder or myWorkspace).
> // - `${rootPath}`: file path of the opened workspace or folder (e.g. /Users/Development/myWorkspace).
> // - `${profileName}`: name of the profile in which the workspace is opened (e.g. Data Science (Profile)). Ignored if default profile is used.
> // - `${appName}`: e.g. VS Code.
> // - `${remoteName}`: e.g. SSH
> // - `${dirty}`: an indicator for when the active editor has unsaved changes.
> // - `${focusedView}`: the name of the view that is currently focused.
> // - `${separator}`: a conditional separator (" - ") that only shows when surrounded by variables with values or static text.
> "window.title": "${dirty}${activeEditorShort}${separator}${rootName}${separator}${profileName}${separator}${appName}",
> ```

Pay particular attention to the descriptions of `rootName` and `remoteName`. Also check if you've changed this setting in a [workspace `.vscode/settings.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) in a way that is causing what you're observing. If that's not the cause, it could have something to do with the SSH extension itself and I'd need to dig into the minified source code.

Comment: My window title configuration seems to be ok. I updated my question above and provided more information.

Comment: the question is the entries in the taskbar context menu for taskbar-pinned applications